# Apache-creating custom login form

Tags: apache, authentication

I'm trying to restrict access to a page on my Apache server, but I want Apache to display a custome login screen I've designed instead of the default splash screen to accept user credentials.

After searching on Google and examining the Apache documentation (which is very vague on how to do this) I'm still at a loss.

I suspect I can do this via a redirection, pointing at the location of my custom login screen but unsure as how to do this... If anyone has attempted this in the past, I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Shaw

Comment: Well that largely depends on what kind of “access restriction” you are using/want to use. If we are talking about HTTP Auth here, there is a module called `mod_auth_form` for what you want, but that is only available for Apache >= v2.3, and of course you would need administrative access to the server to install it.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately I am only running Apache 2.2.6 and I don't want to go through the whole upgrading process unless it's a very last resort (this is a live system). I have full admin access to the server however.

Comment: @CBroe also, I just want to use basic authentication, i have a username and password set in the .htpasswd file.